# Как вернуть массив из функции?

Tags: vba

```
Private Function readCSVFile(ByVal fileName As String) As String()
    Open fileName For Binary As #1
    Dim MyData As String
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    readFile = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
End Function

Sub Sample()
    Dim strData() As String
    strData() = readCSVFile("csv_file.txt")
...
```

Но `strData` почему-то приходит пустой, хотя данные точно есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет присвоения значения функции. Надо:

```
readCSVFile = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Опс.... Спасибо!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь )

Answer (score 1):

В качестве возвращаемого функцией значения можно использовать флаг - как результат удачного выполнения функции. А возвращаемый массив поместить в список аргументов:

```
Private Function readCSVFile(ByVal fileName As String, ArrayRet() as String) As Boolean
    ....
    ' В таком случае обращение выглядит: '

    Dim strData() As String
    if readCSVFile("csv_file.txt", strData()) then
       msgbox "Error opening file",16
    Else 
       ' все ОК '
    end if
end function
```